# Why use &getcwd() and not getcwd() in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl language, and in the code I am using there is this line :

```
$BASEDIR = &getcwd();
```

I am wondering why there is a `&` in front of the call to `getcwd`, and I could not find any reference about that. Could someone help me with this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think beyond `5.0` its not working without `&` in subroutine... Later versions are controlled the `&` might be

Comment: in short, it's not needed there and you almost surely don't ever need it in your own code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It causes the subroutine's prototype to be ignored.

```
$ perl -e'
   sub f($@) { print("@_\n"); }
   my @a = (4,5,6);
   f(4,5,6);
   f(@a);
   &f(@a);
'
4 5 6
3
4 5 6
```

But that's probably not the reason it's used here. After all, `Cwd::getcwd` doesn't have a prototype. `&` can't be used on named operators (i.e. the functions of [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html), e.g. `print`), so some beginners use it on subroutines to distinguish them from operators. I believe this is a practice recommended by a popular Perl book.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! So, as pointed out in comments, I probably won't need it in my code.

Comment: That is correct. I don't think I've ever had to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that it is optional unless you are running a really old version of perl.

For more detail see the [**perlsub**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) man page (run `perldoc perlsub` or `man perlsub` depending on your environment)

> A subroutine may be called using an explicit "&" prefix. The "&" is optional in modern Perl, as are parentheses if the subroutine has been predeclared. The "&" is not optional when just naming the subroutine, such as when it's used as an argument to defined() or undef(). Nor is it optional when you want to do an indirect subroutine call with a subroutine name or reference using the "&$subref()" or "&{$subref}()" constructs, although the "$subref->()" notation solves that problem. See perlref for more about all that.

Comment: It's not actually an optional decoration; it has an effect. See my answer.